# solving this differential equation for $y$, Is it even possible?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

Lets say I have the following:
\begin{gather}
\frac{(y')^3 + 3 y' y'' + y'''}{(y')^2 + y''} = \sqrt{1+(y')^2}\\
\frac{((y')^3+3y' y'' + y''')^2}{((y')^2 + y'')^2} = 1+(y')^2\\
\frac{(y')^6 + 6 (y')^4 y'' y''' + 2 (y')^3 y''' + 9 (y'')^2 (y')^2 + 6 y''y' y''' + (y''')^2}{(y')^4 + 2(y')^2 y'' + (y'')^2} = 1+(y')^2
\end{gather}

In a closed form

Which looks horrible, but i am looking for a solution out of curiosity to see if i can do something interesting with arc length. I have no idea where to even begin, if someone has any advice or even information on whether or not this is possible, which i know are both hard tasks, I would appreciate it a lot.

Comment: I think you want to start by making a substitution of $z = y'$. With this in mind,

$$y'y'' = \frac{1}{2}\frac{d}{dx}(y')^2.$$

Your ODE then becomes

$$\frac{z^3+\frac{3}{2}(z^2)'+z''}{z^2+z'} = \sqrt{1+z^2}.$$ As for how to proceed from here, I'm not sure.